# Route between two networks via multiple central routers

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, linux-networking

I have two networks, and a handful of computers.
I want to fix the central point of failure.

Two Networks:

- Network **`Foo`**: **`172.16.1.0/24`**
- Network **`Bar`**: **`172.16.2.0/24`**

Five Servers, running linux (ubuntu):

- Server **`A`**
- Server **`B`**
- Server **`C`**
- Server **`Y`**
- Server **`Z`**

All servers have one network interace: **`eth0`**. 
Except server **`C`**, which has two interfaces: **`eth0`** ****AND**** **`eth1`**.
Server **`C`** is the only server connected to both networks, and it is the central router between the two networks, it has a dedicated interface for each network, and ipv4 forwarding enabled.

Here is a diagram:
[image: diagram1]

^^ this seems to work quite well, but i want to have some sort of failover or loadbalancing of traffic by adding another central router.

Would it be possible to add another linux server, say server **`D`**, also with two network interfaces, to perform the same function as server **`C`**?

I would like server **`D`** to be a failover or balance the traffic somehow, and figuring out this part is difficult for me.
I am imagining that I can add a secondary route to the same network, and add a metric or weight the route on a node, somehow?

Here is a diagram, which I imagine the solution may look like:

[image: diagram2]

Would it be possible to configure this to either load-balance the traffic between server C and D, or would there be some sort of "failover" option?

Here are some things that I am interested in, but I am not highly skilled in networking scenarios, and I am not sure which would be the most fitting solution:

- **`ip route add via metric preference`**
- **`OSPF`**
- **`BGP`**
- or **`iBGP`** or **`eBGP`** (whats the difference?)
- **`Multi-Path TCP`**
- **`CARP`** or **`VRRP`**

I would like to fix the central point of failure (server C), and duplicate the role of that router. What would be the most practical approach?

Comment: You are probably creating more problems then you are solving with this setup - particularly if you don't want to add complexity to a,b,y,z.  The easiest solution would be to have a standby router D to do IP address takeover of router C if it fails. The metric preference will only help you if the interface goes away, so that won't work to well either - if anything using more specific subnets would work similarly but provide a level of load balancing.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion always the best decision when the server's routing configuration as simple as possible (there is only a default route :) ) and because of the network configuration changes there is no need to configure server too.

I know there are cases when this is not applicable.

So I would implement VRRP.

BTW:
iBGP and eBGP: interior and exterior BGP. First one used within an Autonomous System (AS), second one used between AS-s.